# how to display a dynamic list of values from NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a table view of artists. On clicking which we are taken to a detail view which should list all their albums, year of release and number of songs in each album.

I have an array of dictionaries being passed to a detail view that contains all this information.

What is the best/ simplest method to display this list? As it is dynamic, should i iterate through the array and create labels (if so, please show me an example) or would it be best for me to create another uitableview in the detail view?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push another table view controller down the road. That's what it's designed for: showing lists; and with an unknown amount of data this comes very handy.

If there's a third level with details about each album, that might work best with a static defined layout.